# Unknown graphical item in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am working in Excel 2016. My file contains a series of tables with 3 macros to manipulate data and a status function (which returns `PASSED`, `ALMOST`, `FAILED` or `N/A` for each table row). When I execute my second sub, this symbol blinks fastly:

[image]

What is it? Does this affect macro performances when it blinks fast like that? (I cannot show you the VBA code for confidentality reasons, questions welcome)

Comment: Is the 'graphical item' visible at all times or only when code is running? If you right-click on it, do the context menu options that are displayed give you any clues?

Comment: Looks like a Trace Precedents indicator, with the miniature sheet icon advising the referring cell as being on another sheet. To remove, go Formulas > Formula Auditing > Remove Arrows

Comment: @JohnM this item is only present while running and it's not clickable. I tried right, left and middle click, combinations with Ctrl or Alt and nothing happens

Comment: Check the VBA for any .ShowPrecedents or .ShowDependents commands and remove or comment out where they are not required.

Comment: @CLR  & 5202456 I've clicked on **Remove Arrows** but it shows up when I rerun the VBA sub. I will take a look at those commands. Thanks for putting a name in this item, it is already helpful :)

Comment: Try Formulas (tab) - Formula auditing and press the down arrow of `Error checking` and move the cursor over `Circular References`. If such a circular reference error exists, the cell address will be shown. If not, try clicking on `Trace Error`...